# Looking for a word - prince's clothes

Tags: word-request

Please think of fairytales... What word would you use when you refer to a prince's clothes? Is it a *dress*?

Comment: It depends highly on the setting in which the prince is wearing the clothes, doesn't it?  Thinking of a fairy tale by H.C.Andersen, the king didn't wear anything that day...

Answer (score 5):

If you want a term to describe all of a prince's clothing, I would use *finery*.

> **finery**
>
> Expensive or ostentatious clothes or decoration:
> *officers in their blue, gold, and scarlet finery*
> http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/finery

But if you're looking for the 'dress' part of a fairytale prince's clothes, I think it would be *tunic*.

> **tunic**
>
> A loose garment, typically sleeveless and reaching to the knees, as worn in ancient Greece and Rome.

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/tunic

[image: Man in a green tunic with long sleeves]

Answer (score 2):

[Regalia](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/learner/regalia)

> the special clothes that are worn or objects that are carried at official ceremonies - oxforddictionaries.com

Answer (score 2):

"Raiment" is often used in this context.  "Tunic" refers to a particular garment; "raiment" is more general.

"Garb" or "dress" (without an article) is a rather drab abstract noun for what a person is wearing.  One does not refer to "a garb".  "A dress" (or using "the" to refer to a particular "garment") means an item of clothing that is normally worn by women.  Thus, "a dress" is inappropriate for a (male) prince, unless he is pretending to be a woman.

Answer (score 1):

If I was writing a story I would refer to the Prince's **costume**.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a catch-all for what the prince is wearing, consider **attire**. *The prince's attire was befitting a man of his station.*

If you're trying to find what clothes the prince was wearing, that would be dependent on where the prince was and what his local region wore.